# How to write part of a string bold in Android programmatically?

Tags: java, android, text-formatting

I have been searching on the Internet for a solution to my problem. I need to write some text with headlines. The headlines should be bold. What I found on the Internet is how to write the whole string as bold.

E.g.

**Step 1:** Open Android Studio

**Step 2:** ............

How is that done in Android? Can it be done, or do I have to split the strings e.g. the headline should be a separate string.

I have tried the HTML tag on Android, but I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference`

This I what I tried in Android

```
String[] text = new String[2];
text[0] = "<b>" + "Den første bøn er middagsbønnen" + "</b>" + "Den anden bøn er eftermiddagsbønnen"
tvTitle.setText(Html.fromHtml(text[mPage])); //This line triggers the exception
```

The `mPage` is just the page of the tab as I only want the text to appear in one tab.

EDIT:

My class

```
public class PageFragment_Bontider extends Fragment{

public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

private int mPage;

public static PageFragment_Bontider newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        PageFragment_Bontider  fragment = new PageFragment_Bontider ();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
        }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
        }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bontider, container, false);
        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.bonner);
        ImageView bontider = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        String[] text = new String[2];

        text[1] = "Iblandt forpligtelserne for enhver ansvarlig (mukallaf) er udførelse af de fem " +
                "bønner i løbet af dagen og natten. Eftersom kendskabet til disse bøntider er en " +
                "pligt for enhver ansvarlig, gøres der rede for dem i det følgende:\n\n" +
                "Den første bøn er middagsbønnen (Adh-Dhuhr), hvis tid indtræder, når solen aftager " +
                "fra sit højeste punkt på himlen (midten af himlen) mod vest, og udtræder når skyggen" +
                " af en tilfældig genstand bliver lige så lang som en genstands egen længde adderet " +
                "med længden af kulminationsskyggen. Kulminationsskyggen er den målte skygge, når " +
                "solen er ved sit højeste punkt i løbet af en dag.\n\n" +
                "Den anden bøn er eftermiddagsbønnen (Al-^asr), hvis tid varer fra middagsbønnens " +
                "udtrædelse til solnedgang (når hele solskiven er forsvundet).\n\n" +
                "Den tredje bøn er solnedgangsbønnen (Al-Maghrib), hvis tid indtræder fra " +
                "eftermiddagsbønnens udtrædelse, og udtræder når det rødlige skumringslys " +
                "(svagt lys der dukker op i den vestlige horisont efter solnedgang) er forsvundet.\n\n" +
                "Den fjerde bøn er natbønnen (Al-^Ishaa´), hvis tid indtræder ved solnedgangsbønnens " +
                "udtrædelse, og udtræder ved frembrudet af det sande daggry (Al-Fadjir As-Saadiq), " +
                "hvilket er det vandrette lys, der viser sig i den østlige horisont, som et tyndt " +
                "skær der dernæst udbreder sig.\n\n" +
                "Den femte bøn er morgenbønnen (As-Subh), hvis tid indtræder ved natbønnens udtrædelse, " +
                "og udtræder ved solopgang (Shuruuq).";

        tvTitle.setText(text[mPage]);

        int[] billede = new int[2];

        billede[0] = R.drawable.bontider;

        if(billede[mPage] != 0){
            bontider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            bontider.setImageResource(billede[mPage]);
            tvTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return view;
        }
}
```

Comment: You should ask this as two separate questions since the solution will be very different between Android and iOS.

Comment: This needs to be two separate questions. One for Android/Java and the other for iOS/Swift because it will have two completely different answers solved by different people.

Comment: Also provide a [mcve] and clearly show which line causes the error. It sounds like the first step is to solve the NPE before even worrying about how to use HTML in a TextView.

Comment: Alright, have changed it

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: Everything works fine without the HTML tag. However, when I include the HTML tag I get the exception on the third line (have written a comment to show where)

Comment: Can you try to use `text[0]` in the last line and tell me the result?

Comment: As I stated earlier, you need to show a minimal working example in order for us to help you. The code you have shown here is missing a couple of variable declarations. There is also no class or method. We need these details to understand your code and be able to point you in the right direction without a lot of guess work.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: Have change the OP, and added the class

Comment: Now go read the link I gave earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to create separate text views. You can use `SpannableString` to achieve your goal. Following is the sample code for changing string style in different ways. You will just have to calculate starting and ending index inside the string.

```
SpannableString styledString
  = new SpannableString("Large\n\n"     // index 0 - 5
       + "Bold\n\n"          // index 7 - 11
       + "Underlined\n\n"    // index 13 - 23
       + "Italic\n\n"        // index 25 - 31
       + "Strikethrough\n\n" // index 33 - 46
       + "Colored\n\n"       // index 48 - 55
       + "Highlighted\n\n"   // index 57 - 68
       + "K Superscript\n\n" // "Superscript" index 72 - 83 
       + "K Subscript\n\n"   // "Subscript" index 87 - 96
       + "Url\n\n"           //  index 98 - 101
       + "Clickable\n\n");   // index 103 - 112

 // make the text twice as large
 styledString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0, 5, 0);

 // make text bold
 styledString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 7, 11, 0);

 // underline text
 styledString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 13, 23, 0);

 // make text italic
 styledString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 25, 31, 0);

 styledString.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 33, 46, 0);

 // change text color
 styledString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 48, 55, 0);

 // highlight text
 styledString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.CYAN), 57, 68, 0);

 // superscript
 styledString.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), 72, 83, 0);
 // make the superscript text smaller
 styledString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.5f), 72, 83, 0);

 // subscript
 styledString.setSpan(new SubscriptSpan(), 87, 96, 0);
 // make the subscript text smaller
 styledString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.5f), 87, 96, 0);

 // url
 styledString.setSpan(new URLSpan("http://www.google.com"), 98, 101, 0);

 // clickable text
 ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {

 @Override
 public void onClick(View widget) {
    // We display a Toast. You could do anything you want here.
    Toast.makeText(SpanExample.this, 
    "Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
 };

styledString.setSpan(clickableSpan, 103, 112, 0);

// this step is mandated for the url and clickable styles.
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

// make it neat
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

tvTitle.setText(styledString);
```

Comment: How do I use that to make some of the string bold, and the rest normal?

Comment: styledString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 7, 11, 0);

Answer (score 0):

You can use text spans.

`SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder("Hello, world!");
StyleSpan span = new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);
builder.setSpan(span, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);`

When you set the text, pass the builder directly without invoking `toString()`.